# Get active sheet Excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, openxml

I want to get only active sheet name from excel file using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`,but now i am getting all the sheet names,how can i get only active sheet name from excel using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`?

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
Workbook workbook = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook;
            BookViews bookViews = workbook.GetFirstChild<BookViews>();
            WorkbookView workbookView = bookViews.GetFirstChild<WorkbookView>();
            var activeSheet = workbookView.ActiveTab.InnerText;
            string sheetName = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().ElementAt(Convert.ToInt32(activeSheet)).Name;
```